# Accessing specific value of rows and columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a data set with a few columns and rows

[image: Data set example]

I have to create a bar graph of the mean revenues from the year 2006-2011 and 2012-2016
I've already tried using `if` statements to separate the revenues from 2006-11 and 2012-16 but getting errors.

```
if movie_data['Year']<=2011:
    movie_data['rev_new']=movie_data['Revenue (Millions)']
print(movie_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create two bins for the two time windows by manually specifying your desired time frames

```
bins = pd.cut(pd.to_datetime(df['year']), bins=[pd.to_datetime('2006'), pd.to_datetime('2011'), pd.to_datetime('2016')])
```

Then group your dataframe by these bins and create your bar chart

```
df = df.groupby(bins).mean()
df['Revenue (Millions)'].plot(kind='bar')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the dataframe in this way:

```
before_2011 = movie_data[movie_data['Year'] <= 2011]
after_2012 = movie_data[movie_data['Year'] >= 2012]
```

and access the revenues as:

```
before_2011['Revenue (Millions)']
```

Comment: yea got it mate. Thanks